# I think my kid's Eee Pad has malware. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, malware, ads

As you might expect from a 11 year old, she keeps filling it with games and girly-pop songs. Today, I noticed a strange "pseudo-Market" icon on its home screen:

[image: Eee Pad home screen]

When you click on it, you get the screen below. Looks like spam to install more games. Lots of these show up in the notification area too, but this "pseudo-Market" icon is a first.

Is there a good scanner to get rid of all this nagware?

[image: Tapping the pseudo-Market icon]

Comment: That doesn't look like a pseudo market but the new updated play store.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik Why would Play Store have `Market` as the shortcut text and an old icon like that? This definitely is not the new Play Store.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik I think OP is referring to the icon below the play store.

Comment: Thanks guys  just noticed that one. He said market and when I saw the Play Store icon I stopped looking.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's plenty Android Anti-Malware solutions.

Here's a list ordered by the best results according to [AV-TEST - The Independent IT-Security Institute](http://www.av-test.org/) and the latest test results performed [during February and March 2012](http://www.av-test.org/fileadmin/pdf/avtest_2012-02_android_anti-malware_report_english.pdf), where were reviewed 41 different solutions.

**Detection rates of 90% and above:**

- [avast! Free Mobile Security](http://www.avast.com/free-mobile-security)
- [Dr.Web anti-virus Light](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drweb&hl=en)
- [F-Secure Mobile Security](http://www.f-secure.com/en/web/home_global/protection/mobile-security/overview)
- [IKARUS mobile.security LITE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ikarus.mobile.security&hl=pt_PT)
- [Kaspersky Mobile Security](http://www.kaspersky.com/mobile_downloads)
- [Lookout Security & Antivirus](https://www.mylookout.com/)
- [McAfee Mobile Security](https://www.mcafeemobilesecurity.com/)
- [MYAndroid Protection](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mymobileprotection20&hl=en)
- [NQ Mobile Security](http://en.nq.com/)
- [Zoner AntiVirus Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoner.android.antivirus&hl=en)

**To quote:**

> The best products in our tests (with detection rates of 90% and above) come from the following top 10 companies, listed in alphabetic order: Avast, Dr. Web, F-Secure, Ikarus, Kaspersky, Lookout, McAfee, MYAndroid Protection, NQ Mobile and Zoner. Users of products made by these companies can be assured that they are protected against malware.